# How to sort the id users that have the maximum of a property?

Tags: mysql

How to return the id of users that have the maximum of a property in a database?

**id** A B C

with A B and C being integer?

For instance: if managing a database of users that stole things in a computer game. I want to return users that have stolen the maximum amount of a resource called Metall.

The database sketch is the following:

**id**  Name    Adresse     Verteidiger     Metall  Kristal     Deuterium   Zerstörung  Datum

Even if this is false, I tried:

```
SELECT id I1 FROM `Angriff` WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    SELECT id I2 WHERE Metall > I1.METALL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a single row with a maximum value in MySQL you can simply use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Angriff` 
ORDER BY Metall DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

if there are multiple rows with the same maximum this will return only one randomly.

To get all rows with the same maximum you can modify your query to use a Correlated Subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `Angriff` AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS  -- there's no row with a higher `Metall`
  (  SELECT * FROM `Angriff` AS t2
     WHERE t2.Metall > I1.METALL );
```

A more common way in Standard SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `Angriff`
WHERE Metall = 
  (  SELECT MAX(Metall) FROM `Angriff` );
```